# How to scatter plot 3 columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

Code is below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=["A", "B","C"])
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(df)
df['cluster_id'] = km.labels_
test = {0:"Blue", 1:"Red", 2:"Green"}
#sns.scatterplot()
plt.show()
```

I am trying to plot without `x,y`  that is column constraints. I need to plot any number of columns `just want to plot the cluster graph`

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2), columns=["A", "B","C"])` This wouldn't be working would it?

Comment: @QuangHoang in this situation df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=["A", "B","C"])

Comment: Your problem is how to visualize high-dimension data. For 3-D data (3 columns) you can resolve to [3D scatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html). For higher dimensional data (**any** number of columns) you should look for dimension-reducing techniques, e.g. tSNE or PCA.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: if you have only 3 columns without a column that can be used as a "hue"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot( projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x, y, z,marker='o')

plt.show()
```

x,y,and z are columns from the dataframe of equal length (# of rows)

Method 2: If you have3 columns (equal # of rows) to plot and a 4th column that can be used as a hue. The 4th column is usually your clusters

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

x = df['pc_1']
y = df['pc_2']
z = df['pc_3']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("husl", 256).as_hex())
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c = df['Clusters'], marker='o', cmap=cmap)
plt.legend(*sc.legend_elements(), bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1))

plt.show()
```